# how to remove the 2d texture from OnGui() in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to clear the image  img1.

I have a `void OnGui()` in which i load the image from server as screen
   saver.

I need to remove the image once i touched the screen that means i need
   to deactivate the image texture.

```
void OnGUI()
{
  GUILayout.Label(img1);

  foreach (UnityEngine.Touch touch in Input.touches)
  {
    CancelInvoke(methodName : "ChangeImage");
    img1.enabled=false;//but this line doesn't work
  }
}
```

I load the `img1` from server..it will appear
   only after 30 seconds of inactiveness.

how can i make the `img1` deactivate inside foreach,so that when i touch the screen screensaver `img1` will be disabled.

Comment: Where and how is `img1` declared? When you say it does not work, what is the actual problem? An error? I think this is C# not Unityscript so the tag should be changed.

Comment: public Texture2D img1; @Programmer

Comment: And when do you make the image appear again? Can you post your methodName function too?

Comment: rest every thing is working perfect the only thing is how to make the image texture that appear on the gui disappear..how can we make that image texture disable @Programmer

Comment: Alright then. I put the part you asked in my answer. You have to mix it with your other code that you said you already got working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Texture2D` is a class/Object and not a Component so you can't disable it with `img1.enabled=false`.

Simply wrap a `boolean` variable around `GUILayout.Label(img1);`. This boolean variable should be made to be toggled to `false` when there is a touch on the screen.

```
public Texture2D img1;
bool showImage = true;

void OnGUI()
{
    if (showImage)
    {
        GUILayout.Label(img1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            CancelInvoke(methodName: "ChangeImage");
            showImage = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is wrong because you are using the wrong GUI(*IMGUI*) in Unity. You should be using *uGUI* which is the new Unity UI.

You can do this with the `Image` or `RawImage` component from the new UI system and then be able to enable or disable it.

Got to *GameObject*->*UI*->*RawImage*. Use the code below and drag the RawImage to the `imageDisp` slot.

```
public RawImage imageDisp;
public Texture2D img1;

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            CancelInvoke(methodName: "ChangeImage");
            imageDisp.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also set `imageDisp` to `null` with `imageDisp = null;` but that is not necessary here.