# How to load an image in Unity from a link

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

- I have a scene in which I have declared an image in a canvas
- To that image I need to load an image from a link ("http/assets/screensaver")

I actually have done something to load the image :

```
urllll = "http://192.168.137.129/ooredoo/client_api/" + ConfirmPath;
WWW imgLink1 = new WWW (urllll);
img1 = imgLink1.texture;
```

- But this load the image to the whole scene fully
- I need to load the image on the image which I have declared in canvas

**EDIT:** full code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Common;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using LitJson;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class ScreenSaverFromServer : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text Tester;
public int st = 0;
public int TimerFrAdd = 30;
public int OgTimerFrAdd;
public int ImageSize = 5;
public Image[] Imagez;
public Image Imag;
public int TimeToChangeImage = 10;
public int TimeToChangeVideo= 10;
public string imagePath = "Assets/Images/1K.png";
public Image photo;
public Texture2D img1;
public string urllll;
public string ConfirmPath;
public string[] paths = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"}; 
public string[] VedioPaths = { "Look at NEW Trump's 2-minute closing argument ad.mp4","The 2 minutes love story of TV Commercial for Canon 'You are my inspiration'.mp4"};
public string ConfirmPath1;
public  int PathNO1;
public int PathNO ;
public bool guitextureindi = true;
public Image guitextureindFrame;
public string screensavertype,ImageFrameIndic;

void Start () 
{
    OgTimerFrAdd = TimerFrAdd;
    Tester = GameObject.Find ("Tester").GetComponent<Text> ();
    InvokeRepeating("touches1", 1, 1);

    Imag = GameObject.Find("ImageFrame").GetComponent<Image>();

    Imag.enabled = false;

    screensavertype = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("screensavertype");
    ImageFrameIndic = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("screensaverActive");
}

void Update ()
{
    foreach (UnityEngine.Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        print ("touched");

        if (TimerFrAdd == 0) 
        {
            InvokeRepeating("touches1", 1, 1);
        }

        TimerFrAdd = OgTimerFrAdd;
        Imag.enabled = false;
    }

    if (guitextureindFrame.enabled) 
    {
        guitextureindi = true;
    }

    if(screensavertype == "0")
    {
        Imag.enabled = false;
    }
}

public void touches1()
{
    TimerFrAdd = TimerFrAdd - 1;
    Tester.text = TimerFrAdd.ToString ();
    if (TimerFrAdd == 0) 
    {
        if(ImageFrameIndic == "1")
        {
            Imag.enabled = true;
        }

        CancelInvoke (methodName : "touches1");

        string[] CallChange = {"ChangeImage","ChangeVideo" };
        System.Random random0 = new System.Random();
        int PathNO0 = random0.Next (CallChange.Length);
        string ConfirmPath0 =  CallChange[PathNO0];

        print (ConfirmPath0);

        InvokeRepeating ("ChangeImage", 1, TimeToChangeImage);
    }
}

public void ChangeImage()
{
    //System.Random random = new System.Random();
    //PathNO = random.Next (paths.Length);
    //ConfirmPath =  paths[PathNO];
    //photo.sprite =Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/"+ConfirmPath) as Sprite ;
    print("aaaaaaaa");
    StartCoroutine (LoadImg1()); 
}


public void ChangeVideo()
{
    Imag.enabled = false;
    CancelInvoke (methodName : "ChangeImage");
    CancelInvoke (methodName : "touches1");
    CancelInvoke (methodName : "ChangeVideo");

    System.Random random1 = new System.Random();
    PathNO1 = random1.Next (VedioPaths.Length);
    ConfirmPath1 =  VedioPaths[PathNO1];
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (ConfirmPath1,Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);

    if (TimerFrAdd == 0) 
    {
        InvokeRepeating("touches1", 1, 1);
        TimerFrAdd = OgTimerFrAdd;
    }
}

IEnumerator LoadImg1()
{
    yield return 0;

    //List<string> Items13 = new List<string> (ScreenSaverCodesApi.Items12);
    List<string> Items13 = ScreenSaverCodesApi.Items12;

    print("aaaaaaaa2222222");
    System.Random random1 = new System.Random();
    print("aaaaaaaa333333");
    int PathNO = Items13.Count;

    int num = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,PathNO);
    print(num);

    foreach (string st in Items13) {
        print (st);
    }
    print ("path-----"+Items13[num]);
    string ConfirmPath =  Items13[num];
    print(ConfirmPath);
    print("aaaaaaaa555555");   
    urllll = "http://hcfhfch/nn/client_api/" + ConfirmPath; // test with an image link

    print("aaaaaaaa6666666");

    WWW imgLink1 = new WWW (urllll);
    print("aaaaaaaa777777");
    print (urllll);
    print("aaaaaaaa888888");
    yield return imgLink1;
    print("aaaaaaaa999999");

    img1 = imgLink1.texture;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    foreach (UnityEngine.Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        guitextureindi = false;
    }

    if (guitextureindi) 
    {
        GUILayout.Label (img1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Programmer  i need to display an image from internet... that to i need to display the image by scaling to lower size than the original,,my code displays the image on full screen

Comment: Search google for "html in unity3d". I bet with one of those solutions you'd get what you want.

Comment: my problem is i am not able to scale the image which i have loaded from the net

Comment: yes ..how is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are downloading a texture and storing it in the `img1` variable which is a type of a `Texture2D`. The Texture2D image is then displayed with  `GUILayout.Label` in the `OnGUI` function. The problem is resizing the image...

Like I mentioned in your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358385/3785314) post, do **not** use the `OnGUI` function. Do **not** use any Unity API that requires the `OnGUI` function *unless* you are making an Editor plugin.

In your function,

```
void OnGUI()
{
    foreach (UnityEngine.Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        guitextureindi = false;
    }

    if (guitextureindi) 
    {
        GUILayout.Label (img1);
    }
}
```

Pass the the `width` and `length` you want to the `GUILayout.Label` function.

For example:

```
public float textureWidth = 400;
public float textureHeight = 400;

public Texture2D img1;
void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.Label(img1, GUILayout.Width(textureWidth), GUILayout.Height(textureHeight));
}
```

**The proper/correct way to display image in Unity**:

With the [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) Component:

```
public float textureWidth = 400;
public float textureHeight = 400;

public Texture2D img1;
public Image textureDisplayer;

void SomeFunction()
{
    textureDisplayer.sprite = Sprite.Create(img1, new Rect(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight), new Vector2());
}
```

With the [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) Component:

```
public int textureWidth = 400;
public int textureHeight = 400;

public Texture2D img1;
public RawImage textureDisplayer;

void SomeFunction()
{
    img1.Resize(textureWidth, textureHeight);
    textureDisplayer.texture = img1;
}
```

You can also resize the `Image` or `RawImage` on the screen with:

```
textureDisplayer.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(textureWidth, textureHeight);
```

Simple download, resize and display Image Sample:

```
public int textureWidth = 400;
public int textureHeight = 400;

public RawImage textureDisplayer;

void Start()
{
    string imageUrl = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    StartCoroutine(LoadImg(imageUrl));
}

void displayImage(Texture2D imgToDisp)
{
    //Resize Image
    textureDisplayer.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(textureWidth, textureHeight);
    textureDisplayer.texture = imgToDisp;
}


IEnumerator LoadImg(string url)
{
    yield return null;
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    displayImage(www.texture);
}
```